# SwiftUI: Why is that headers doesn't pin in scrollview which has vertical and horizontal scroll?

Tags: swiftui, gridview, sticky

Following this SO answer I created a excel like table as shown in the below gif. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71154712/4442254

What I want to do is while the scroll view scrolling for both vertical and horizontal, BY YEAR columns should be pinned in order to see which year has which kind of statistic data easily.

```
@State private var frames: [CGRect] = []

let columns = ["BY YEAR", "TEAM", "MIN", "PTS", "FGM", "FGA", "FG%", "3PM", "3PA", "3P%", "FTM", "FTA", "FT%", "OREB", "DREB", "REB", "AST", "STL", "BLK", "PF"]
let byYearKeyPath = \StatsData.game?.season

@State private var columnWidths: [CGFloat] = Array(repeating: 60, count: 20)
@State private var offset = CGPoint.zero

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue._50
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical], showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                        // Header Row
                        Text("Player Stats")
                        headerRow
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            .sticky(frames)

                            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 50) {
                                ForEach(statsData, id: \.id) { data in
                                    HStack {
                                        ForEach(columns.indices, id: \.self) { columnIndex in
                                            dataRow(data: data, columnIndex: columnIndex)
                                                .frame(width: columnWidths[columnIndex])
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
                }
                .coordinateSpace(name: "container")
                .onPreferenceChange(FramePreference.self, perform: {
                    frames = $0.sorted(by: {
                        $0.minY < $1.minY
                    })
                })
                .onAppear {
                    Task {
                        do {
                            statsModel = try await MatchScoresClient.liveValue.fetchStats(String(player.id))
                            if let data = statsModel?.data {
                                statsData = data.sorted { $0[keyPath: byYearKeyPath] ?? 0 > $1[keyPath: byYearKeyPath] ?? 0 }
                            }
                        } catch(let error) {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> **headerRow** creates a horizontally-scrolling header row with column
> titles taken from an array named columns. The width of each column is
> determined by the corresponding value in the columnWidths array. Each
> time the available geometry changes, it recalculates the column
> widths.

```
    private var headerRow: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(columns.indices, id: \.self) { columnIndex in
                        Text(columns[columnIndex])
                            .frame(width: columnWidths[columnIndex])
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .onChange(of: geometry.size) { newSize in
                    updateColumnWidths(geometry: newSize)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> **dataRow** generates a Text view that displays a particular piece of data from a StatsData object, corresponding to a specified column. The exact data displayed depends on the implementation of the dataValue(data: columnName:) function

```
    private func dataRow(data: StatsData, columnIndex: Int) -> Text {
        let columnName = columns[columnIndex]
        return Text(dataValue(data: data, columnName: columnName))
    }
```

> dataValue sets **columns** data with the related rowsData

```
    private func dataValue(data: StatsData, columnName: String) -> String {
        switch columnName {
        case "BY YEAR":
            return "\(data.game?.season ?? 0)"
        case "TEAM":
            return data.team?.abbreviation ?? ""
        case "MIN":
            return data.min ?? ""
        case "PTS":
            return "\(data.pts ?? 0)"
        case "FGM":
            return "\(data.fgm ?? 0)"
        case "FGA":
            return "\(data.fga ?? 0)"
        case "FG%":
            return String(format: "%.2f", data.fgPct ?? 0.0)
        case "3PM":
            return "\(data.fg3M ?? 0)"
        case "3PA":
            return "\(data.fg3A ?? 0)"
        case "3P%":
            return String(format: "%.2f", data.fg3Pct ?? 0.0)
        case "FTM":
            return "\(data.ftm ?? 0)"
        case "FTA":
            return "\(data.fta ?? 0)"
        case "FT%":
            return String(format: "%.2f", data.ftPct ?? 0.0)
        case "OREB":
            return "\(data.oreb ?? 0)"
        case "DREB":
            return "\(data.dreb ?? 0)"
        case "REB":
            return "\(data.reb ?? 0)"
        case "AST":
            return "\(data.ast ?? 0)"
        case "STL":
            return "\(data.stl ?? 0)"
        case "BLK":
            return "\(data.blk ?? 0)"
        case "PF":
            return "\(data.pf ?? 0)"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }

    private func updateColumnWidths(geometry: CGSize) {
        let availableWidth = geometry.width
        let equalWidth = availableWidth / CGFloat(columns.count)
        columnWidths = Array(repeating: equalWidth, count: columns.count)
    }
}
```

> **PreferenceKey** is used to store an array of CGRects. When multiple views in the hierarchy set this preference key, all their CGRect values are collected into one array

```
struct FramePreference: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [CGRect] = []
    
    static func reduce(value: inout [CGRect], nextValue: () -> [CGRect]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}
```

> Offsets the content vertically. If **isSticking** is **true**, it offsets by **frame.minY**, otherwise it doesn't offset the content. Update the frame when the GeometryReader appears or when its frame changes.

```
struct Sticky: ViewModifier {
    var stickyRect: [CGRect] = []
    @State var frame: CGRect = .zero
    
    var isSticking: Bool {
        frame.minY < 0
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .offset(y: isSticking ? frame.minY : 0)
            .zIndex(isSticking ? .infinity : 0)
            .overlay(GeometryReader {
                proxy in
                let frm = proxy.frame(in: .named( "container"))
                Color.clear
                    .onAppear { frame = frm}
                    .onChange(of: frm) { frame = $0 }
                    .preference(key: FramePreference.self, value: [frame])
            })
    }
}

extension View {
    func sticky(_ stickyRects: [CGRect]) -> some View {
        modifier(Sticky(stickyRect: stickyRects))
    }
}
```

[image: Related screen rec]