# Need a SwiftUi table with fixed row headers and column headers which is horizontally and vertically scrollable

Tags: swiftui

This is related to stackoverflow question -
[SwiftUI: Pin headers in scrollview which has vertical and horizontal scroll in excel like view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71122712/swiftui-pin-headers-in-scrollview-which-has-vertical-and-horizontal-scroll-in-e/78233279#78233279)

Thanks for the amazing answer. I have a related question.

1. I would like to make first value in each row as the row headers and they are fixed when horizontal scroll happens.
2. Move the column header to one cell left and leave no empty left top corner.

I was able to make first column or first value in each row as the row headers and start the table but could not move the column headers to one cell left and there is gap in row headers and the rest of the row values.

Here is code followed by the result which has issues-

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

```
@State private var offset = CGPoint.zero
@State private var colsHeaders: [String] = []
@State private var rowData: [[String]] = []

var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Color.clear.frame(width: 150, height: 50)
            ScrollView([.vertical]) {
                rowsHeader
                    .offset(y: offset.y)
            }
            .disabled(true)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        }
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ScrollView([.horizontal]) {
                colsHeader
                    .offset(x: offset.x)
            }
            .disabled(true)
            
            table
                .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .onAppear {
        readJSONFromFile()
    }
}

var colsHeader: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(colsHeaders, id: \.self) { header in
            Text(header)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                //.font(.caption)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                .border(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}

var rowsHeader: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(0..<rowData.count, id: \.self) { row in
            Text(rowData[row].first ?? "N/A")
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                //.font(.caption)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                .border(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}

var table: some View {
    ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal]) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<rowData.count, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(1..<rowData[row].count, id: \.self) { col in
                        // Cell
                        
                        Text(rowData[row][col])
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                            .border(Color.gray)
                            .id("\(row)_\(col)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background( GeometryReader { geo in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: geo.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin)
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { value in
            print("offset >> \(value)")
            offset = value
        }
    }
}
here is the screenshot -
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Uqs.png
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks @ChrisR and @corleyq

Comment: Why not just use Table?

Comment: It is using table.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Table

Comment: Oh the ' SwiftUI Table'. It does not give you the scrolling. And also the row headers and column headers should not move with horizontal and vertical scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution -

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var offset = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var colsHeaders: [String] = []
    @State private var rowData: [[String]] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
               // Color.clear.frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                ScrollView([.vertical]) {
                    rowsHeader
                        .offset(y: offset.y)
                }
                .padding(.top, 50.0)
                .disabled(true)
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ScrollView([.horizontal]) {
                    colsHeader
                        .offset(x: offset.x)
                }
                .padding(.leading, -150.0)
                .disabled(true)
                
                table
                    .coordinateSpace(name: "scroll")
            }
            .padding(.leading, -60.0)
            
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            readJSONFromFile()
        }
    }
    
    var colsHeader: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(colsHeaders, id: \.self) { header in
                Text(header)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    //.font(.caption)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                    .border(Color.gray)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var rowsHeader: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<rowData.count, id: \.self) { row in
                Text(rowData[row].first ?? "N/A")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    //.font(.caption)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                    .border(Color.gray)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var table: some View {
        ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal]) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<rowData.count, id: \.self) { row in
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(1..<rowData[row].count, id: \.self) { col in
                            // Cell
                            
                            Text(rowData[row][col])
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                                .border(Color.gray)
                                .id("\(row)_\(col)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background( GeometryReader { geo in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self, value: geo.frame(in: .named("scroll")).origin)
            })
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) { value in
                print("offset >> \(value)")
                offset = value
            }
        }
    }
    
    func readJSONFromFile() {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AIRsp", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonResponse = try decoder.decode(JsonResponse.self, from: data)
                self.colsHeaders = jsonResponse.responseData.gridColumns.map { $0.name }
                self.rowData = jsonResponse.responseData.gridRows
            } catch {
                print("Error reading JSON file: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGPoint
    static var defaultValue = CGPoint.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value.x += nextValue().x
        value.y += nextValue().y
    }
}
Screenshot -
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```